# TypeError: unhashable type: list in len(re.findall())

Tags: python

I am programming a very simple KENO sim for a school assignment.
Very basic Python knowledge.
I am getting a TypeError: unhashable type: list

**Here is my entire code if relevant:** (Specific section below)

```
import random
from random import randrange
import sys
import re
def keno_sim():

    acceptable_values = list(range(1, 40))    
    number_no = int(input("How many numbers would you like to input? (MIN: 1 MAX: 40): "))
    if number_no in acceptable_values:
        print ("Pick your numbers, (between 1-80), seperated by commas ")
        answer = input("> ").split(",")
    else:
        print ("Please choose a number that's 1-40")

    random_number = random.sample(range(1, 80), number_no)
    print ("Your numbers are:",answer)
    print ("The generated numbers are:",random_number)
    matches = len(re.findall(answer, random_number))

    if matches > 0.5 * random_number:
        print ("You win!")
        print ("You had",matches,"matches!")

    elif matches < 0.5 * random_number:
        print ("Close! but wrong number!")
        print ("You had",matches,"matches!")

print("This is KENO\n")
print("GENERAL RULES:\nPick how many numbers you’d like to play, ranging from 1 to 40. Same numbers are drawn from the 80 available on the Keno game grid, if you match more than half of them, you win!")
keno_sim()

again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
if again == ["yes", "Yes", "yess", "y","ye", "yea"]:
    keno_sim()
else:
    print ("Thanks for playing ,name, !")
    sys.exit(0)
```

**Specific Section:**

```
    matches = len(re.findall(answer, random_number))

    if matches > 0.5 * random_number:
        print ("You win!")
        print ("You had",matches,"matches!")

    elif matches < 0.5 * random_number:
        print ("Close! but wrong number!")
        print ("You had",matches,"matches!")
```

Please give a specific fix or examples if possible

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` takes two `str`ings, but you are giving it two `list`s, and lists are unhashable because they are mutable. Instead of

```
matches = len(re.findall(answer, random_number))
```

try something like

```
matches = len(set(answer).intersection(random_number))
```

---

Unrelated, but you also might want to do something like

```
answer = [int(x) for x in input("> ").split(",")]
```

and

```
if matches > 0.5 * len(random_number):
    ...
elif matches < 0.5 * len(random_number):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

're.findall()' is related to regular expressions and it is not working with lists, only with strings. In your case, you can find matches using sets:

1. convert your lists into sets

   `set1 = set([int(item) for item in answer]`

   `set2 = set(random_number)`
2. find their intersection:

   `intr = set1.intersection(set2)`
3. find the length of the intersection:

   `matches = len(intr)`